# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in " triggered by Datatables plugin and jQuery 1.11.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm using the jQuery Datatables plugin to enable pagination, sorting and searching with my tables. The elements are showing up but not working, and the pagination only sometimes shows up. In Chrome console I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in
```

[Here is the demo page.](http://proxy-checker.jamesallison.co/view.php?code=f3935da410f9020c70a2e0dde185354c)

I'm using Bootstrap alongside this plugin.

Comment: James it will be tremendous help in debugging and finding the problem if you use unminified versions of libraries and scripts in demo.

Comment: Faced similar issue, solved it by  latest datatables: 1.10.19 with jquery-rails (4.3.3)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That error is because of the method `isArraylike` in jQuery version 1.11.3. (only). The method looks like this

```
function isArraylike( obj ) {

    // Support: iOS 8.2 (not reproducible in simulator)
    // `in` check used to prevent JIT error (gh-2145)
    // hasOwn isn't used here due to false negatives
    // regarding Nodelist length in IE
    var length = "length" in obj && obj.length, // <------ THIS IS THE CULPRIT
        type = jQuery.type( obj );

    .......
}
```

That version of jQuery was using "length" in object to get the length. (I do not know anything about it).

**But I do know that no other versions of jquery have that issue.**

The versions 1.11.3 and 2.1.4 (as James pointed out in the comments) have this issue.

So the solution would be to just upgrade to the next version or at least use any other version apart from 1.11.3 or 2.1.4

Comment: Please re-check the demo - I've changed to jQuery version 2.1.4, and still not working

Comment: I literally checked all the versions from 1.11.0 till 2.1.3 and I left 2.1.4 and the issue is there :D

Comment: Haha very weird, thank you I've opted for 2.1.3 now :)

Comment: If on rails this helps: https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/VERSIONS.md - also funny how I skip over certain words like 'apart from' and just go grab the latest version 2.1.4...so future readers, try 2.1.3, which is jquery-rails 4.0.4, and specify in your application.js `/= require jquery2`

Comment: This just fixed a 4 hour bug hunt. Using jquery-rails 4.0.3 personally, but it's working. I'm sure 4.0.4 works too.

Comment: It's also happening in 3.0.0

Comment: Nice way to explained. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: it happens in 3.3.1 as well.

Comment: Not in 1.11.3 for sure check this http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 8):

I'm working on Ruby on Rails with gem jquery-datatables-rails.

I update the gem directly from the last commit on GitHub:

```
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: "rweng/jquery-datatables-rails", branch: "master"
```

This work for me, I suppose that that they will release soon a new version of the gem with this commit.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that worked for me.  Hopefully the fix will get released soon.

Comment: Thanks this helped for me as well

Answer (score 6):

Upgrading to DataTables to DataTables `1.10.7` or  `1.10.8-dev` did not work for me (using jQuery `1.11.3`).

Downgrading to jQuery `1.11.2` did work (using DataTables `10.0.0`)

Comment: Can confirm. I was using jQuery  2.1.4 and Datatables 10.0.4. Upgrading to  DataTables 1.10.7 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

No need to downgrade jQuery. 
I solved the same error by using `aoColumns` as

```
$('#id').DataTable( {
    data: [["A", "B"], ["a", "b"]],
    'aoColumns': [ 
        { sWidth: "50%", bSearchable: false, bSortable: false }, 
        { sWidth: "50%", bSearchable: false, bSortable: false }
        ],
    } );
```

I am using `jQuery 2.1.4` and `DataTables 1.10.9`

Answer (score 3):

Whilst unrelated to DataTables, I came across this "cannot use in operator to search for length" error. This was the main Google result for the error so just wanted to post my issue as a response in case it helps anyone else.

I had:

```
ApplicationIDs: $.map(".application-checkbox:checked", function (checkedApplicationCheckbox, i) {
```

I'd forgotten to wrap my selector with the `$` so the fix was to make sure I was passing the actual jQuery elements as the first argument to `map` and not just a string...

```
ApplicationIDs: $.map($(".application-checkbox:checked"), function (checkedApplicationCheckbox, i) {
```

I'm almost embarrased to post this ;)

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I fixed a similar issue by adding the json dataType like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "someUrl",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        varname1 : "varvalue1",
        varname2 : "varvalue2"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (varname, varvalue){
            ...
        });  
    }
});
```

And in my controller I had to use double quotes around any strings like so (note: they have to be escaped in java):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someUrl", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String getJsonData(@RequestBody String parameters) {
    // parameters = varname1=varvalue1&varname2=varvalue2
    String exampleData = "{\"somename1\":\"somevalue1\",\"somename2\":\"somevalue2\"}";
    return exampleData;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, LeHill  - I'm using jQuery 2.2.4 and this fixed my issue!

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same issue but jQuery version was not the culprit for me. In my case, I was incorrectly serializing the form. The code ended up with this error was:

```
$('#form_name').serialize()
```

Whereas I should have used.

```
$('#form_name').serializeArray()
```

I did this and my issue was resolved.

Just throwing out this little piece that I ignored. Could help someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the root cause of this error was due to invalid columns details passed in ajax data table calling.

```
$("#example1").DataTable({            
        searching: false,            
        paging: false,
        serverSide: true,        
        ajax: {
            url:"data-url",
            type:"post",                
            data:{
                key:"key_id"
            }
        },
        columns: [
           {"data":"column_1","name":"column_name_1"},                                      
           {"data":"EScore","name":"EScore"}
        ]
});
```

earlier i faced "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' when i was passing

```
columns: ["column_1","column_2"]
```

i resolved this by passing it with correct structure

```
columns: [ 
    {"data":"column_1","name":"column_name_1"},                                      
    {"data":"EScore","name":"EScore"}
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

With DataTables and calling a PHP-script with AJAX, be aware that you just must **echo your array** at the end. There is no need of encoding it first to a JSON object with json_encode.

So

```
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8'); 
echo $myArray // This will do. Do not use echo json_encode($myArray);
exit();
```

Otherwise you might end up with the dreadful error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

or this one

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined