# Autocomplete with MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

Hello I have troubles with type of JSON data.

> ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 4444

444 - this is my data sending back to jquery.

This is my code:

JQUERY:

```
$('.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    minLength:1,
    source: 'http://localhost/instaling/autocomplete.php',
    select:function(evt, ui)
    {
      this.form.city.value = ui.item.german;
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
$searchWord = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));

$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `polish` LIKE '%$searchWord%'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
  $german = $row['german'];    
}

echo json_encode($german);
```

What's wrong with codes? I used encode in php to send data as JSON to jquery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in " triggered by Datatables plugin and jQuery 1.11.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31149836/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-length-in-trigge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'test');
require_once "inc/db.php";
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
$term=$_GET['term'];
    $return_arr = array();
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `polish` LIKE '%$searchWord%'");       
       $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $return_arr[] =  $row['german'];
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    /* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
```

Comment: $return_arr[] =  $row['german']; This is what I'm looking for. Thank you :)